# Как переместить объект созданный нажатием мыши

Tags: c++, qt

Пусть у меня на `QGraphicsScene` есть `QGraphicsItem` представляющий кучу камней.
У меня с помощью `mousePressEvent` (клика по куче камней) создается объект `QGraphicsItem` представляющий собой один камень.

> Как мне сделать так, чтобы не отжимая кнопку мыши я мог перемещать
> этот создавшийся камень?

Мне нужно подсказать направление мысли, целый код я не прошу потому что вопрос получился абстрактным

Answer (score 1):

```
class Stone: public QGraphicsItem {
public:
    Stone(): ..., pressed(false) {
    }

    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) {
        pressed = true;
    }

    void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) {
        if (pressed) {
            // Перемещаем объект вместе с мышью. 
            // Координаты для объекта берем из event
        }
    }

    void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) {
        pressed = false;
    }

private:
    bool pressed;
}
```

Comment: вы второй метод перепутали с Release и у вас два метода Press в итоге

Comment: @MegaMan копипаст :)

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, я не понял как внедрить решение Александра.

Оставляю этот ответ, чтобы помочь страждущим,таким как я.

В итоге я решил проблему следующим способом:

> В конструкторе кучи я создаю элемент камня и просто напросто прячу
> его.
>
> Таким образом при следующим клике на кучу мы уже можем с ним работать.
>
> При клике на кучу мы просто показываем камень и в методе
> mouseMoveEvent кучи его двигаем.

Возможно это костыльно и велосипедно,но я первый раз работаю с QT.
Более подробную реализацию можно увидеть тут: https://github.com/religious0atheist/nim_games